# Decorator not implementing decorated interface

Tags: java, design-patterns

I have my small project where I wrapped object of one class with another class. Decorated class implements one interface but Decorator class does not implement it. I am curious whether it is still decorator pattern or some other pattern and "Decorator" class should be called Wrapper instead of Decorator in my project.

I have checked iluwatar github repository (https://github.com/iluwatar/java-design-patterns/tree/master/decorator/src/main/java/com/iluwatar/decorator) and tutorialspoint (https://www.tutorialspoint.com/design_pattern/decorator_pattern). 
For example in iluwatar there is:
Decorator:

```
public class ClubbedTroll implements Troll
```

Decorated:

```
public class SimpleTroll implements Troll
```

In both cases (iluwatar and tutorialspoint) there is common interface implementation in decorator and decorated class. Does it mean it is mandatory to call it decorator design pattern?

Comment: I don't understand the point in trying to find out if your solution to an (I guess) mostly artificial problem has to stick to a certain design pattern - design patterns are *best practice solutions* for common problems and have no value of their own, so if you would ask us if a Decorator might be a good solution for your problem we could help, but right now it's not that meaningful.

Comment: `public class ClubbedTroll extends SimpleTroll` ...

Comment: If the 'decorator' is not implementing the decorated interface it is not a decorator since it cannot act like the decorated type. Then it's only a wrapper. The Decorator _IS_  the decorated type with additional functionality. **Decorator and decorated must be the same type (share the same interface or base class)**. Try [this](https://www.tutorialspoint.com/design_pattern/decorator_pattern).

Answer (score 2):

I'd say if you don't implement the interface in your decorator, then it simply cannot act like the original thing (decorated). If you're implementing the interface, you can use the decorator everywhere you could have done it with the original interface if classes. That's why you have to use the interface.

If you just wrap the decorated, you've got a wrapper (delegation pattern).

Answer (score 1):

The essense of Decrator pattern is to add additional functionality to an object without extending it. The key word is *additional*, which means that the public API (or interface) of the object still stays the same. Without this concept there's no point of using Decorator.

So the question actually is "Does an object still provide the same public API without implementing an `interface`?"

IMHO, it could be possible in some other language, but in Java it makes no sense, since you can not guarantee an object has the same public API and, therefore, rely on it.

As to Wrapper - this is another name for [Adapter pattern](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Adapter_pattern).

Comment: Decorator and Decorated must be interchangeable. The caller expects interface `TypeA` so the decorator must be assignable to variable of type `TypeA` and behave like a `TypeA`. The decorator therefore _must_  implement `TypeA`. `TypeA decorated = new Decorated()` must work like `TypeA impl = new Decorator(decorated)` and therefore decorator and decorated are interchangeable.